# Attach Elastic IP to EC2 instance of Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

My production and development application are running on EBS's EC2 instances where I need to attach an elastic IP to each instance. I am able to associate the elastic IPs to each instance but after some time the IPs disassociated automatically due to application load balance which creates a new instance of EC2, I know it's due to Application Loadbalance but I want to know how can I persist the elastic IPs to each instance? I am using third party integration in which I have to send my static IPs to make them whitelisted.

Comment: It's the auto-scaling group that is creating new instances, not the application load balancer. However, you might want to explain why you need elastic IPs assigned to all your EC2 instances. That's generally an anti-pattern in an auto-scaled environment, and there are probably other AWS solutions for the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @MarkB my bad for the wrong wording, as I mention I am integrating third party APIs in my application and my 3rd party needs IP addresses so they can do a whitelist entries in their system, so requests from x.x.x.x (my instances elastic IP) can call their API, currently I have to associate elastic IP again when disassociated automatically, any solution for this would be great!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The AWS solution for sending requests to third parties from a fixed IP (or fixed set of IPs) when running in an auto-scaled environment is to create a [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) in your public subnet (or one in each public subnet), assign Elastic IPs to the NAT Gateways, and place your EC2 instances in private subnets with a route to the NAT Gateway.

In this configuration, all outbound requests will go through the NAT Gateway(s) which will have static (Elastic) IPs that can be whitelisted by third-parties.